# PointCut expressions in spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have two pointcut expressions:

1. `* *..*Repository.find*(..)`
2. `* *Repository.find*(..)`

What is the difference between these two and what does the `*..`part  of the first pointcut means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do read through the official documentation section **"Declaring a Pointcut"**. See the [examples](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/ataspectj/pointcuts.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) for more details.

```
execution(modifiers-pattern?
          ret-type-pattern
          declaring-type-pattern?name-pattern(param-pattern)
          throws-pattern?)
```

#### `* *..*Repository.find*(..)`

| Pattern type | Pattern | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ret-type-pattern | `*` | any |
| declaring-type-pattern | `*..*Repository` | Type with a name that ends with `Repository` within **any package *except for* the root (default) package** |
| ?name-pattern(param-pattern) | `find*(..)` | A method with a name that starts with `find` accepting any number (zero or more) of parameters |

#### `* *Repository.find*(..)`

| Pattern type | Pattern | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ret-type-pattern | `*` | any |
| declaring-type-pattern | `*Repository` | Type with a name that ends with `Repository` within **root (default) package only** |
| ?name-pattern(param-pattern) | `find*(..)` | A method with a name that starts with `find` accepting any number (zero or more) of parameters |

The difference is that the second expression is specific about the package where the type exists. Please note that the first package noes **not** include the root package, which is one of the many reasons that Java code should never be declared in the default package.

`..` is a special wildcard to match any number of arguments and `*..*` in `declaring-type-pattern` means starting from root package and any of its sub-package.

Comment: This is a great answer. I took the liberty of re-formatting it and explaining that `*..*` does **not** match the default package, which is a caveat that was not mentioned explicitly before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer of this question you will find in [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/ataspectj/pointcuts.html#aop-common-pointcuts)

About your topic:
`* *..*Repository.find*(..)`
This pointcut matches any method starts with find with any numbers of params and is located in any classes that are invoking some method that are ending with `Repository.find`

`* *Repository.find*(..)`
This pointcut mean anything that match this one and method find have any number of params

Comment: Sorry, this answer is completely incomprehensible. Please improve it.

Comment: I did it, i think that now is more clearly sorry for discomfort. And also i think that the OP will get it.